# reverse the order of menu items on an arabic website mobile menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using foundation for designing a responsive menu in my website. i have both arabic and english site setup. the english version is displaying correctly but in the arabic website i would like to reverse the menu order but only when the mobile menu is triggered.
http://www.abdulazizlp.com/arabic/home-1

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
     <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Comment: When you say reverse the menu order, do you mean that you want the "Right nav Section" to be on the left side, and the "Left Nav Section" to be on the right side?

Comment: No i want the menu items to be displayed like last one first by only when the mobile menu is triggered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/xk7d1hre/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">1 Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">2 Right Button Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">1 First link in dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">2 Active link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

**JQ:**

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    $ul=$(this);        
    $ul.find('li').each(function(){
        if($(this).parents('.dropdown').size()==0)        
        $ul.prepend($(this));        
    })
})

$('ul.dropdown').each(function(){
    $ul=$(this);        
    $ul.find('li').each(function(){    
        $ul.prepend($(this));        
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Foundation has a function that lets you check if a Media Query is present. So, using this, we can first check for the "small" media query (presumably the size of mobile clients), and if its there, then we can use some jQuery to reverse the menu items.

The javascript/jQuery:

```
if (window.matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries.small).matches) {

    var $menus = $(".top-bar-section").find("ul");
    $menus.each(function(){
        var $ul = $(this);        
        $ul.children('li').each(function(){
            $ul.prepend($(this));        
        });
    });
}
```